# Irreducible algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

One can show that an irreducible algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^2$ must be either a curve or a point (or of course the entire space). However the situation in $\mathbb{A}^3$ and higher dimensions is vastly more complicated.

My question: is there any higher significance to the classification of irreducible algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^2$? Are there any important results which depend on this classification in a crucial way?

Comment: I don't understand, why it is more complicated. the point is that any irreducible algebraic set of $A^n$ would have a smaller dimension. of course, you can classify curves and it has many applications but usually, the point is that you can classify all varieties of dimension 1  not that you can classify subspace of $A^2$

Comment: The upshot of classification in any part of mathematics in simply that they give a (more or less) complete understanding of the studied objects. Think back to linear algebra: You fully classified vector spaces through their dimensions and hence had a good understanding of vector spaces. Similarly e.g. the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, etc etc.